# OpenInChrome from Google not detecting or opening Google Chrome app in iOS 9

Tags: google-chrome, ios9

Has anyone figured out how to detect that Google Chrome is installed and then open it from your own app with link passed into it in iOS 9?

I used to use the [OpenInChromeController](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/OpenInChrome) which according to [Google](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/ios/links) is the recommended approach. It does not appear that Google is updating that document for iOS 9, and OpenInChromeController appears to be abandoned.

Comment: Based on this [post](http://awkwardhare.com/post/121196006730/quick-take-on-ios-9-url-scheme-changes) I added "googlechrome" & "googlechromes" to my info.plist URL Schemes. I think that might do the trick but I won't know until Google Releases a Chrome app with iOS 9. I think thats probably the best guess we can make until Google Releases Chrome with iOS 9 support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out, you just need to add it to your plist as LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and then you can use canOpenUrl to see if the app is installed

`<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
     <string>urlscheme</string>
     <string>urlscheme2</string>
     <string>urlscheme3</string>
     <string>urlscheme4</string>
    </array>`

Answer (score 4):

I think a more detailed answer would be adding the following three schemes to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in `YOURAPP-Info.plist`

- googlechrome
- googlechromes
- googlechrome-x-callback

For more detail please reference [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/?q=openInChrome)